# Delete selected row in database

Tags: java, jdbc

Why is this not working for me? I keep getting the error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().
```

My code:

```
private void speler_deleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int row = tbl_spelers.getSelectedRow();
    int SpelerID = (int) tbl_spelers.getValueAt(row, 0);
    Speler speler = new Speler();

    try {
    DBClass databaseClass = new DBClass();
    Connection connectie = databaseClass.getConnection();
    // NOG ONVEILIG - WACHTEN OP DB SELECT IN DBCLASS!!!
    String deleteQry = "DELETE FROM `Speler` WHERE SpelerID = " + SpelerID + ";";
    ResultSet rs = databaseClass.GetFromDB(deleteQry);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use [`excuteUpdate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29)  for **delete**.

Docs of  [`excuteUpdate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29)

> Executes the given SQL statement, which may be an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as an SQL DDL statement.

Where as [`executeQuery()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29)

> Executes the given SQL statement, which returns a single ResultSet object.

Answer (score 0):

executeQuery() method of jdbc is to select records, you can use executeUpdate() for update operations. Please refer to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) for the purpose/ intent of each method:

> ```
> boolean execute()
> ```
>
> Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which may
>   be any kind of SQL statement.
>
> ```
> ResultSet executeQuery()
> ```
>
> Executes the SQL query in this PreparedStatement object and returns
>   the ResultSet object generated by the query.
>
> ```
> int executeUpdate()
> ```
>
> Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which
>   must be an SQL INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement; or an SQL statement
>   that returns nothing, such as a DDL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to use `excuteUpdate()` for the delete, and next

```
String deleteQry = "DELETE FROM `Speler` WHERE SpelerID = " + SpelerID + ";";
```

remove the `semi-colon` and the "`" which encloses the table name "Speler", from the query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute you query using **`executeUpdate()`**

Also, you just need to make a slight adjustment to your String `deleteQry` as follows:

```
String deleteQry = "DELETE FROM Speler WHERE SpelerID = " + SpelerID;
```

Hope this helps...